# redirect to different views in laravel logged in users based on role mentioned by using if condition in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

In laravel i have student,parent ,employee(Teacher,Librarian,warden) roles with different permissions...based on user role it should redirect to different blade files when user logged in..my problem is if user parent or student it is redirecting to different dashboards but whenever user is teacher or other it does not logged in but in users table already user exist.

below is my LoginController code

LoginController.php:

```
public function login(Request $request){


    if(Auth::attempt([

          'email'=>$request->email,
          'username'=>$request->username,
          'password'=>$request->password,


    ]))

    {
        $user=User::where('username',$request->username)->first();
        $usertype=$user->user_type;
        $username=$user->username;

        $roles=DB::table('roles')->where('id','=',$usertype)->first();

        $rolename=$roles->role_name;



        if($rolename=="student"){

           $student=DB::table('students')->where('stud_adm_id','=',$username)->first();
           $classid=$student->class_id;
           $sectionid=$student->section_id;
           $class=DB::table('classtables')->where('id',$classid)->first();
          $section=DB::table('sections')->where('id',$sectionid)->first();

          return view('studentdashboard',compact('student','class','section'));

        }elseif($rolename=="Teacher"){



          $employeedetails=DB::table('employees')->where('employee_fname','=',$username)->first();

        return view('teacherdashboard',compact('employeedetails'));

    }
        elseif($rolename=="parent"){

            $parentdetails=DB::table('parents')->where('mother_phone','=',$username)->first();
           $stateid=$parentdetails->state;
           $state=DB::table('states')->where('state_id','=',$stateid)->first();

            return view('parentdashboard',compact('parentdetails','state'));

      }

  }else{


 return redirect()->back();

  }
}
```

my roles are mentioned in role table and that id stored in users table

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what happens when you try to login with teacher's credentials? Do you get any response?

Comment: no not getting any response just blink and redirects to same login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better create a middleware to check user role, and based on the role redirect user to different pages!

Run the command below to create a middleware that checks user's role.

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckRoleMiddleware
```

The command will create a file under `App\Http\Middleware` named `CheckRoleMiddleware` this class will come a predefined method `handle()` there you can place the logic that checks user's role and redirects them to different pages example:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckRoleMiddleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //User role is admin
        if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin() )
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        //If user role is student
        if(Auth::check() && auth()->user()->role === 'student')
        {
             return view('studentDashboard');
             or route('routeName');
        }

        //If user role is teacher
        if(Auth::check() && auth()->user()->role ==='teacher')
        {

             return view('teacherDashboard');
             or route('routeName');

        }
        //default redirect
        return redirect('home');

    }

}
```

And don't forget to add `CheckRoleMiddleware` to `App\Http\Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'user-role' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CheckRoleMiddleware', // this line right here
];
```

Comment: what would they be applying this middleware to?

Comment: @lagbox you can add that part, since you are are a great so editor!

Comment: if this middleware was assigned to any routes the user would constantly end up with the same view being rendered and not able to get to any routes .. unless they were an admin

Comment: this middleware will stop anyone who isn't an 'admin' from getting to the actual route this middleware would be applied to ... its right there in the code clearly .... it has nothing to do with any action after login

Answer (score 0):

Lets just ignore everything about how this stuff should work and how it does by default and take what you have.

Do you see a problem here:

```
if ($rolename == "student")

elseif ($rolename == "Teacher")

elseif ($rolename == "parent")
```

If not, lets try it this way:

```
student
Teacher
parent
```

Which one is not like the others? And which one was the one that "was not working" correctly?

I would like to assume you have these roles named in a consistent fashion, so `Teacher` should be `teacher`.

Comment: I guess this is a comment, not an actual answer.

Comment: no its an answer "`Teacher` should be `teacher`", the rest is leading to the answer

Answer (score -3):

You can do all of what you want to do with the default `LoginController` by overriding a method or two.

You should not be returning views from processing routes. `POST REDIRECT GET`. POST comes in, return a REDIRECT, that causes a GET request (which most likely is going to return a view).

For validating the login credentials:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => '...',
        'username' => '...',
        'password' => '...',
    ]);
}
```

For what credentials should be used from the request:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only('email', 'username', 'password');
}
```

The response to return after successful authentication:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    // do your role checking here
    // return a redirect response to where you want that particular user type to go
    // return redirect()->route(...);
}
```

Everything related to building the views and gathering that data is its own route. All you have to do is return a redirect for the login flow. Where you redirect to is responsible for gathering the data needed to display a view.